# How to change text color of a specific lines in Python

Tags: textcolor

My program change all text lines into one single color

I tried using

```
print("\033[1;32m")
```

but it doesn't accomplish my necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Add a message:

```
print("\033[1;32m" + "message")
```